# Treeset to order elements in descending order

Tags: java, collections, treeset

Here is the piece of code that I have used for Java 5.0

```
TreeSet<Integer> treeSetObj = new TreeSet<Integer>( Collections.reverseOrder() ) ;
```

`Collections.reverseOrder()` is used to obtain a comparator in order to reverse the way the elements are stored and iterated.

Is there a more optimized way of doing it?

Comment: Flip the order of ```this``` and ```that``` in the overridden ```compareTo``` so items are inserted in the opposite order.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Why do you think this approach won't be optimized?  The reverse order `Comparator` is simply going to be flipping the sign of the output from the actual `Comparator` (or output from `compareTo` on the `Comparable` objects being inserted) and I would therefore imagine it is very fast.

An alternative suggestion: Rather than change the order you store the elements in you could iterate over them in descending order using the `descendingIterator()` method.

Comment: Thanks. descendingIterator() method was introduced in 6.0 and was not there in 5.0

Answer (score 10):

## `TreeSet::descendingSet`

In Java 6 and later, there is a method on [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) called [`descendingSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingSet()) producing a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface object.

> public NavigableSet descendingSet()
>
> The descending set is backed by this
>   set, so changes to the set are
>   reflected in the descending set, and
>   vice-versa. If either set is modified
>   while an iteration over either set is
>   in progress (except through the
>   iterator's own remove operation), the
>   results of the iteration are
>   undefined.
>
> ```
>     The returned set has an ordering equivalent to
> ```
>
> Collections.reverseOrder(comparator()).
>   The expression
>   s.descendingSet().descendingSet()
>   returns a view of s essentially
>   equivalent to s.
>
> ```
>     Specified by:
>         descendingSet in interface NavigableSet<E>
>
>     Returns:
>         a reverse order view of this set
>     Since:
>         1.6
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
TreeSet<Integer> treeSetObj = new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>()
  {
  public int compare(Integer i1,Integer i2)
        {
        return i2.compareTo(i1);
        }
  });
```

there is need to flip the result. But I guess this is **just a [micro-optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/99445/34735)**... Do you really need this ?

Answer (score 4):

Using descendingSet method you can reverse existing treeSet in the class

```
import java.util.TreeSet; 
  
public class TreeSetDescending { 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // Declare a treeset 
        TreeSet<Object> ints = new TreeSet<Object>(); 
        ints.add(2); 
        ints.add(20); 
        ints.add(10); 
        ints.add(5); 
        ints.add(7); 
        ints.add(3); 
  
        // Initialize treeset with predefined set in reverse order 
        // using descendingSet() 
        TreeSet<Object> intsReverse = (TreeSet<Object>)ints.descendingSet(); 
  
        // Print the set 
        System.out.println("Without descendingSet(): " + ints); 
        System.out.println("With descendingSet(): " + intsReverse); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Reverse `compare`

You can reverse the order of the two arguments in the [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) method of your [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
TreeSet t = new TreeSet(new MyComparator());
  {
class MyComparator implements Comparator
{
  public int compare(Integer i1,Integer i2)
        {
         Integer I1=(Integer)i1;
         Integer I2=(Integer)i2;
         return I2.compareTo(I1);  // return -I1compareTo(I2);
        }
}
  }
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of the much older [Answer by Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090989/642706).