# Can TreeSet be sorted in opposite way when objects are already in the set?

Tags: java, sorting, treeset

Can `TreeSet` be sorted in opposite way when objects are already in the set?

I mean, I inserted 10^6 words in a `TreeSet` and I want to sort it now the opposite way. To my knowledge this is not possible, but I need to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Treeset to order elements in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090969/treeset-to-order-elements-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TreeSet.descendingSet()` to return a reverse view of it. You should always read the javadocs (and then Google) before asking a question here or anywhere else.